# Есть ли способ в spring узнать, сколько времени осталось до выполнения метода по таймеру?

Tags: java, spring

Например, у меня есть метод, выполняющийся раз в секунду:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000L)
public void cacheUpdates(){
    //мой код
}
```

Можно ли в произвольном месте в программе, сколько в данный момент осталось времени до следующего выполнения метода? Если нет, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: вам надо зафиксировать время последнего вызова, а потом сравнивать с текущим.